# Firebase function using onCreate not running on document creation

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.sendNewDealAlert = functions.firestore
  .document("Live_Deals/{documentId}")
  .onCreate((change, context) => {
    async function main() {
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: "removed",
        port: 465,
        secure: true, //
        auth: {
          user: "removed",
          pass: "removed",
        },
      });

      let info = await transporter.sendMail({
        from: '"Fred Foo " <foo@example.com>',
        to: "removed",
        subject: "Hello ✔",
        text: "Hello world?",
        html: "<b>Hello world?</b>",
      });

      console.log("Message sent: %s", info.messageId);

      console.log("Preview URL: %s", nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    }

    main().catch(console.error);
  });
```

What I am trying to do here is get this function to trigger every time a new document is created inside the collection "Live Deals".

It is not showing that the function is running in the function logs on firebase once I create a new document inside of the collection, so it does not appear to be working.

After trying a few different solutions for the past 2 hours I decided to ask for some help. I believe I may just have the part above setup wrong somehow?

Comment: How are you trying to trigger this Cloud Function?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen id like it to trigger when a new document is created inside the collection Live Deals =]

Comment: There is some important code missing, to know what your doing wrong here. I've used such a hook before and it works just fine.

Comment: How are you testing that? Also: what's inside the body? If you don't think it's being triggered at all, adding a `console.log` right inside there wouldn't show. It really helps if you show a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as we're looking at a complete, standalone repro.

Comment: You name the collection `Live Deals` (with a space) in your question, but the code uses `Live_Deals` with an underscore. `Live Deals` <> `Live_Deals`, so make sure they match.

Comment: Added the full code. My other functions are working fine, just this one is not triggering when a document is created inside Live Deals collections like I thought it would setup this way.

Comment: Please do the test with a `console.log` that I mentioned earlier. I also highly recommend studying the link, as you're using quite a few technologies here, and it's not immediately clear (from the code + output) which one is failing.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen without _ it will not deploy I figured the _ was needed for the spacing there am I wrong? Running it with console.log now, I thought it will still show it running in my firebase functions log even without a console.log. It should which is why I did not add one. My other functions just show they ran in the firebase functions log without a console.log added or so I thought lol.

Comment: Add the client code please.... if your not writing to "Live_Deals" thats your issue... btw defining that function in the onWrite is deeply wierd

Comment: Its def because of the Live Deals and Live_Deals but for some reason it will not deploy if I use "Live Deals" there so im trying to figure out whats up with that now. Looks like I cant use spaces in the collection name.

Comment: Just use an underscore in both... the important thing is consistancy between the collection name used in the client code and the function code

Comment: Yup I fixed it by just making the collection with an underscore and it solved it =] Thanks man!